# Adding tag or text before number

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to add a `<br>` to this text

```
SD0000000266675 - JAIME ANDRES SAAVEDRA BETANCURTSD0000000266675 - HORACIO PALACIOS
```

Something like this (adding a `br` tag):

```
SD0000000266675 - JAIME ANDRES SAAVEDRA BETANCURT<br>SD0000000266688 - HORACIO PALACIOS
```

Problem: text **is dynamically generated.**

Comment: Will it always have "SD" at the start of the serial number?

Comment: what about the length of the serial number? will it be the same always?

Comment: @RaheelHasan: It's at the start of the string.

Comment: @Raheel Nope. the length can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var t = "SD0000000266675 - JAIME ANDRES SAAVEDRA BETANCURTSD0000000266675 - HORACIO PALACIOS"
var p = t.indexOf(t.split(/\s/)[0], 1);
t.substr(0, p) + '<br>' + t.substr(p)
```

Meaning: take the first word (until the first space), find it somewhere else in the string, then insert whatever you're trying to insert there.

EDIT: per your comment, for multiple rows:

```
var t = "SD0000000266675 - JAIME ANDRES SAAVEDRA BETANCURTSD0000000266675 - HORACIO PALACIOSSD0000000266675 - JAIME ANDRES SAAVEDRA BETANCURTSD0000000266675 - HORACIO PALACIOSSD0000000266675 - JAIME ANDRES SAAVEDRA BETANCURTSD0000000266675 - HORACIO PALACIOSSD0000000266675 - JAIME ANDRES SAAVEDRA BETANCURTSD0000000266675 - HORACIO PALACIOSSD0000000266675 - JAIME ANDRES SAAVEDRA BETANCURTSD0000000266675 - HORACIO PALACIOS"
var d = t.split(/\s/)[0];
var s = t.split(new RegExp('(?=' + d + ')'));
s.shift();
s.join('<br/>')
```

(works only if the identifier is guaranteed not to contain any weird characters; if not, then either rephrasing would work, or using one of the [`RegExp.escape` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318729/240443).

Comment: thanks! Could you explain a little more? this works but I dont  understand the space word part.

Comment: Will it work if the string has more than two serial numbers (delimeters) in it? It doesn't for me given the string is `SD0000000266675 - JAIME ANDRES SAAVEDRA BETANCURTSD0000000266675 - HORACIO PALACIOSSD0000000266675 - JAIME ANDRES SAAVEDRA BETANCURTSD0000000266675 - HORACIO PALACIOSSD0000000266675 - JAIME ANDRES SAAVEDRA BETANCURTSD0000000266675 - HORACIO PALACIOSSD0000000266675 - JAIME ANDRES SAAVEDRA BETANCURTSD0000000266675 - HORACIO PALACIOSSD0000000266675 - JAIME ANDRES SAAVEDRA BETANCURTSD0000000266675 - HORACIO PALACIOS`

Comment: What if my string dont have the "sd" part only the numbers?

Comment: @JuanFernandoz: Edited. Doesn't matter what the identifier is, as long as its first appearance is delimited by a space, and it doesn't contain any RegExp special operators. Any numbers and letters are fine.

Answer (score 0):

if Serial starts with SD and length is at least 13, try this RE (regex):

```
Replace this:
/(SD[0-9]{13,}[\s]{0,1}-[\s]{0,1}.*?)/i
with:
<br>$1
```

*in php, you would use preg_replace function for this.*

Comment: `@Raheel Nope. the length can change`