# How do I make case-insensitive queries on Mongodb?

Tags: regex, mongodb, database

```
var thename = 'Andrew';
db.collection.find({'name':thename});
```

How do I query case insensitive? I want to find result even if "andrew";

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Is it possible to make a case-insensitive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query)

Comment: A note to everyone who will attempt to use an answer involving regexes: Regexes need to be sanitized.

Comment: @sean, can you add an answer using sanitized regex, I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Chris Fulstow's solution will work (+1), however, it may not be efficient, especially if your collection is very large. Non-rooted regular expressions (those not beginning with `^`, which anchors the regular expression to the start of the string), and those using the `i` flag for case insensitivity will not use indexes, even if they exist.

An alternative option you might consider is to denormalize your data to store a lower-case version of the `name` field, for instance as `name_lower`. You can then query that efficiently (especially if it is indexed) for case-insensitive exact matches like:

```
db.collection.find({"name_lower": thename.toLowerCase()})
```

Or with a prefix match (a rooted regular expression) as:

```
db.collection.find( {"name_lower":
    { $regex: new RegExp("^" + thename.toLowerCase(), "i") } }
);
```

Both of these queries will use an index on `name_lower`.

Comment: Great answer, my regex approach really slows down once it has to scan a few million docs.

Comment: This is actually not fully correct, because you might find "Andrew something" while looking for "Andrew". So adjust the regex to: `new RegExp('^'+ username + '$', "i")` to be an exact match.

Comment: According to MongoDB website any case insensitive regex is not index efficient "$regex can only use an index efficiently when the regular expression has an anchor for the beginning (i.e. ^) of a string and is a **case-sensitive match**"

Comment: With Mongoose this worked for me : User.find({'username': {$regex: new RegExp('^' + username.toLowerCase(), 'i')}}, function(err, res){
            if(err) throw err;
            next(null, res);
        });

Comment: Never forget to escape the name when working with regular expressions. We do not want injections to take over the beauty of mongodb. Just imagine you used this code for a login page and the username was `".*"`.

Comment: @dcrosta when i use it in java api its shows error. in new RegExp db.collection.find( {"name_lower":
    { $regex: new RegExp("^" + thename.toLowerCase(), "i") } }
);?

Comment: There has been an issue open with mongodb for 5 years to add case insensitive indexes.  They still have not made the change.  I wonder why.

Comment: Be wary when using this. If the value is user controlled, they can easily use regex in their queries. Such as: `/users/thena,*`, which would get the user with the username "thename"

Answer (score 141):

You'd need to use a case-insensitive [regular expression](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions) for this one, e.g.

```
db.collection.find( { "name" : { $regex : /Andrew/i } } );
```

To use the regex pattern from your `thename` variable, construct a new [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object:

```
var thename = "Andrew";
db.collection.find( { "name" : { $regex : new RegExp(thename, "i") } } );
```

**Update:** For exact match, you should use the regex `"name": /^Andrew$/i`. Thanks to  Yannick L.

Comment: Do you know how to do this using Node.js mongoose ?

Comment: I wonder how well this will work with large collections. You'd loose the benefit of a sort functinon

Comment: This is wrong, it will match any document _containing_ "andrew" for `name`, not just equaling.

Comment: @JonathanCremin to help people you should post the correct answer: `{ "name": /^Andrew$/i }`

Comment: @YannickL. 1+ for doing the common sense thing. I was just passing by not what i was looking for.

Comment: This is not the answer for anyone who will be dealing with large amounts of data.  Unlike Mysql, a case insensitive regex in Mongodb does not currently use an index.  Thas means searches get slow and expensive on sizeable data sets.

Answer (score 68):

I have solved it like this.

```
 var thename = 'Andrew';
 db.collection.find({'name': {'$regex': thename,$options:'i'}});
```

If you want to query for case-insensitive and exact, then you can go like this.

```
var thename =  '^Andrew$';
db.collection.find({'name': {'$regex': thename,$options:'i'}});
```

Comment: This was the only solution worked for me. ( Node.js,  "mongoose": "^7.2.0" )

Answer (score 14):

1. With Mongoose (and Node), this worked:

   - `User.find({ email: /^name@company.com$/i })`
   - `User.find({ email: new RegExp(``^${emailVariable}$`, 'i') })
2. In MongoDB, this worked:

   - `db.users.find({ email: { $regex: /^name@company.com$/i }})`

Both lines are case-insensitive. The email in the DB could be `NaMe@CompanY.Com` and both lines will still find the object in the DB.

Likewise, we could use `/^NaMe@CompanY.Com$/i` and it would still find email: `name@company.com` in the DB.

Comment: Thank you Raymond. It worked `User.find({ email: new RegExp(`^${emailVariable}$`, 'i') })` example

Answer (score 12):

MongoDB 3.4 now includes the ability to make a true case-insensitive index, which will dramtically increase the speed of case insensitive lookups on large datasets.  It is made by specifying a collation with a strength of 2.

Probably the easiest way to do it is to set a collation  on the database.  Then all queries inherit that collation and will use it:

```
db.createCollection("cities", { collation: { locale: 'en_US', strength: 2 } } )
db.names.createIndex( { city: 1 } ) // inherits the default collation
```

You can also do it like this:

```
db.myCollection.createIndex({city: 1}, {collation: {locale: "en", strength: 2}});
```

And use it like this:

```
db.myCollection.find({city: "new york"}).collation({locale: "en", strength: 2});
```

This will return cities named "new york", "New York", "New york", etc.

For more info: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90

Comment: strength: 1 is sufficient for case-insensitive, diacritic-insensitive indexing.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/

Answer (score 8):

**... with mongoose on NodeJS that query:**

```
const countryName = req.params.country;

{ 'country': new RegExp(`^${countryName}$`, 'i') };
```

or

```
const countryName = req.params.country;

{ 'country': { $regex: new RegExp(`^${countryName}$`), $options: 'i' } };

// ^australia$
```

or

```
const countryName = req.params.country;

{ 'country': { $regex: new RegExp(`^${countryName}$`, 'i') } };

// ^turkey$
```

**A full code example in Javascript, NodeJS with Mongoose ORM on MongoDB**

```
// get all customers that given country name
app.get('/customers/country/:countryName', (req, res) => {
    //res.send(`Got a GET request at /customer/country/${req.params.countryName}`);

    const countryName = req.params.countryName;

    // using Regular Expression (case intensitive and equal): ^australia$

    // const query = { 'country': new RegExp(`^${countryName}$`, 'i') };
    // const query = { 'country': { $regex: new RegExp(`^${countryName}$`, 'i') } };
    const query = { 'country': { $regex: new RegExp(`^${countryName}$`), $options: 'i' } };

    Customer.find(query).sort({ name: 'asc' })
        .then(customers => {
            res.json(customers);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // error..
            res.send(error.message);
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference between the first method and the third method?

Comment: Be caution! This approach don't use indexes. It may cause slow queries on large databases.

Answer (score 6):

To find case Insensitive string use this,

```
var thename = "Andrew";
db.collection.find({"name":/^thename$/i})
```

Comment: Why are you adding a duplicate answer as it is already there in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7101868/4273915

Answer (score 5):

I just solved this problem a few hours ago.

```
var thename = 'Andrew'
db.collection.find({ $text: { $search: thename } });
```

- Case sensitivity and diacritic sensitivity are set to false by default when doing queries this way.

You can even expand upon this by selecting on the fields you need from Andrew's user object by doing it this way:

```
db.collection.find({ $text: { $search: thename } }).select('age height weight');
```

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text

Comment: $text performs a text search on the content of the fields indexed with a text index.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Case Insensitive Indexes**:

The following example creates a collection with no default collation, then adds an index on the name field with a case insensitive collation. [International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/)

```
/*
* strength: CollationStrength.Secondary
* Secondary level of comparison. Collation performs comparisons up to secondary * differences, such as diacritics. That is, collation performs comparisons of 
* base characters (primary differences) and diacritics (secondary differences). * Differences between base characters takes precedence over secondary 
* differences.
*/
db.users.createIndex( { name: 1 }, collation: { locale: 'tr', strength: 2 } } )
```

To use the index, queries must specify the same collation.

```
db.users.insert( [ { name: "Oğuz" },
                            { name: "oğuz" },
                            { name: "OĞUZ" } ] )

// does not use index, finds one result
db.users.find( { name: "oğuz" } )

// uses the index, finds three results
db.users.find( { name: "oğuz" } ).collation( { locale: 'tr', strength: 2 } )

// does not use the index, finds three results (different strength)
db.users.find( { name: "oğuz" } ).collation( { locale: 'tr', strength: 1 } )
```

or you can create a collection with default collation:

```
db.createCollection("users", { collation: { locale: 'tr', strength: 2 } } )
db.users.createIndex( { name : 1 } ) // inherits the default collation
```

Answer (score 4):

This will work perfectly
`db.collection.find({ song_Name: { '$regex': searchParam, $options: 'i' } })`

Just have to add in your regex `$options: 'i'` where **i** is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 3):

To find case-insensitive literals string:

#### Using regex (recommended)

```
db.collection.find({
    name: {
        $regex: new RegExp('^' + name.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + '$', 'i')
    }
});
```

#### Using lower-case index (faster)

```
db.collection.find({
    name_lower: name.toLowerCase()
});
```

Regular expressions are slower than literal string matching. However, an additional lowercase field will increase your code complexity. When in doubt, use regular expressions. I would suggest to only use an explicitly lower-case field if it can replace your field, that is, you don't care about the case in the first place.

Note that you will need to escape the name prior to regex. If you want user-input wildcards, prefer appending `.replace(/%/g, '.*')` after escaping so that you can match "a%" to find all names starting with 'a'.

Answer (score 2):

Regex queries will be slower than index based queries.

You can create an index with specific collation as below 
`db.collection.createIndex({field:1},{collation: {locale:'en',strength:2}},{background : true});`

The above query will create an index that ignores the case of the string. The collation needs to be specified with each query so it uses the case insensitive index.

Query
`db.collection.find({field:'value'}).collation({locale:'en',strength:2});`

*Note* -  if you don't specify the collation with each query, query will not use the new index.

Refer to the mongodb doc here for more info - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/

Answer (score 1):

The following query will find the documents with required string ***insensitively         and with global occurrence also***

```
db.collection.find({name:{
                             $regex: new RegExp(thename, "ig")
                         }
                    },function(err, doc) {
                                         //Your code here...
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

in mongoose Schema in the type definition of the field you want to search let say email just add property **`lowercase:true`**

Answer (score -3):

An easy way would be to use $toLower as below.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            name: { $toLower: "$name" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            name: the_name_to_search
        }
    }
])
```