# Case Insensitive Mongodb C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am using Query.In in c# but i want to make query case insenstive ? Is there any way to make
it case insensitive.

```
Query.In("subjects", new BsonArray(model.subjects))
```

I want query to match both "Maths" and math.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a Regex? Probably not very efficient, but at least working:

> db.collection.find( { "subjects" : { $regex : /yourString/i } } );

Also have a look at: [How do I make case-insensitive queries on Mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101703/how-do-i-make-case-insensitive-queries-on-mongodb)

Comment: I am using Query Collection in query , so regex would not be a option,