# regex use with $where on mongoose/mongoDB

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to pull out the results from mongoDB using mongoose ORM. 
The below code part worked perfectly and returned the exact matches of 'Test'

```
db.getCollection('cards').find({
    $where: "this.name=='Test'"
})
```

I actually wanted to pull out the case-insensitive matches of 'Test'.

Below one worked,

```
db.getCollection('cards').find({"name":/test/i})
```

But I wanted to use regex on $where as below,

```
db.getCollection('cards').find({
    $where: "this.name=='/Test/i'"
})
```

can someone throw some light or direction on how to address regex within $where?

Comment: @npinti this is not a duplicate as my requirement is to use $where keyword

Comment: @Cling: I wasn't sure, so I did not vote to close. Thanks for the correction. comment removed.

Comment: @Cling You might be "using" `$where` but you probably should not be unless you need more JavaScript based logic in there than what you are doing. JavaScript evalution can "only" scan the entire collection. A proper "$regex" query can at least just scan the entire index. And even less of the index if you include a caret `^`

Comment: Dupicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101703/how-do-i-make-case-insensitive-queries-on-mongodb

Comment: whats the reason for downvotes??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('cards').find({"name": /Test/i})
```

the above query will give you any name containing "test" in it

if you want to do a search with using `$where`

use this:

```
db.getCollection('cards').find({ $where: "/Test/.test(this.name)" })
```

IMHO you can use [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) itself.

```
{ <field>: { $regex: /pattern/, $options: '<options>' } }
```

example:

```
db.getCollection('cards').find({ name: { $regex: /Test/, $options: 'i' } })
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. This is what exactly I am looking for. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey @Cling just out of my curiosity , which one did you use ?

Comment: I used,
db.getCollection('cards').find({ $where: "/Test/i.test(this.name)" })

The one with $where, I would need to make some more manipulations after this...

Comment: @Cling glad to know I helped :)