# req.params is working with $regex of mongodb

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb

for this query i am getting the result of all the documents where the sensor name id d

```
db.sensors.find( { "sensorData.sensorName" : { $regex : /d/i } } );
```

but when try usiing this query with nodejs route i am getting empty array back
router.get('/api/sensorsDetails/isUnique/:sensorName',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.params.sensorName)

```
SensorsModel.find({"sensorData.sensorName":{ $regex : /req.params.sensorName/i }},function (err,result) {

    console.log(result)
    if (err) {
        res.send(err.stack)
    }
    else {
        if(result.length>0){
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ status: false}))
        }else{
            res.send(JSON.stringify({ status: true}))
        }
    }
})
```

please help whats is wrong with second query

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101703/how-do-i-make-case-insensitive-queries-on-mongodb

Comment: i tried like this SensorsModel.find({"sensorData.sensorName":{ $regex : "/"+req.params.sensorName+"/i" }} but i am getting a empty result even thought there is a match

Comment: Sure, you are passing a regex literal inside a C string literal, which is not correct. To pass a variable into a regex, use a RegExp constructor: `SensorsModel.find({"sensorData.sensorName":{ $regex : RegExp(req.params.sensorName, "i") }} `