# In mongodb how to ignore case sentive case?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.tasks.find({ name: {$regex: '^T',$options: "x"}},{name:1});
```

it working fine when I enter Capital Letter for example T but when I enter lower case letter for example it is not working

```
db.tasks.find({name: {$regex: '^[a-zA-z]T',$options: "x" }}, {name:1});
```

Please help me

Comment: use `$option: "ix"` for case insensitive

Comment: Have you even tried to google? :v

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest if you're using mongo3X version please go for case-insensitive collation index.

MongoDB introduced this concept in it's 3.4 version. You can use this case-insensitive search over even high volumes of data.

Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101703/how-do-i-make-case-insensitive-queries-on-mongodb) to get more idea on how it works.

Moreover you can use regex as well, But it is purely depends on your requirements how frequently you need to query for case-sensitive text.

Hope this will helpful for you.!

Comment: now i set default_language none and it is working. Thanks