# I want to check if the user exists but it also have to support case sensitive

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to check the user if exists but in case sensitive, For example= `ABC` is existing and if user type `abc` or `Abc` than it should say that name exists

This is my current logic

```
company_model.companySchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    try {
        cModel.find({ name: this.name }, function (err, docs) {
            try {
                if (!docs.length) {
                    next();
                } else {
                    console.log('company name exists: ', this.name);
                    next(new Error("Company Name exists!"));
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('error in cModel.find: ' + e.message)
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('error in pre save : ' + e.message)
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you seen?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993773/contains-case-insensitive

Comment: @bakar_dev I am unable to struct that logic with my code, can you help me with that?

Comment: so you want case **in**sensitive

Comment: @bakar_dev - that won't help since it's some database ... perhaps [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101703/how-do-i-make-case-insensitive-queries-on-mongodb) is better - which is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query) - so, a simple search on SO would've found at least two duplicates

Comment: @Bravo can you help me with code? editing it?

Comment: `cModel.find({ name: { $regex: new RegExp(\`^${this.name}$\` , 'i') } }, ....`

Comment: You can make the data you get in your database lowercase and change the user input also into lowercase then compare it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Is it possible to make a case-insensitive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query)