# Case Insensitive search with $in

Tags: mongodb, nosql

How to search a column in a collection in mongodb with `$in` which includes an array of elements for search and also `caseInsensitive` matching of those elements in the column ?

Comment: Apart from the $in operator, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query

Comment: Ya right. my question was basically related to caseinsensitive match with $in operator.

Comment: You can use $caseSensitive: false. Refer here : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) with regular expressions search, e.g. let's search for "**blue**" color in the following collection:

```py
db.items.save({ 
  name : 'a toy', 
  colors : ['red', 'BLUE'] 
})
```

```
> ok
```

```py
db.items.find({
  'colors': {
    $elemMatch: { 
      $regex: 'blue', 
      $options: 'i' 
    }
  }
})
```

```
>[ 
  {   
    "name": "someitem",
    "_id": { "$oid": "4fbb7809cc93742e0d073aef"},   
    "colors": ["red", "BLUE"]
   }
]
```

Comment: One note: this regex will not use index. So, such solution does not fit for 'big data'. Another solution is to support same lowercased array.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for mentioning that.

Comment: this is not useful when the we need to check over a array of value

Answer (score 17):

Use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) with the match being case insensitive:

Data example:

```
{ 
    name : "...Event A",
    fieldX : "aAa" 
},
{ 
  name : "...Event B",
  fieldX : "Bab" 
},
{ 
  name : "...Event C",
  fieldX : "ccC" 
},
{ 
  name : "...Event D",
  fieldX : "dDd" 
}
```

And we want documents were "fieldX" is contained in any value of the array (optValues):

```
var optValues = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'];

var optRegexp = [];
optValues.forEach(function(opt){
        optRegexp.push(  new RegExp(opt, "i") );
});

db.collection.find( { fieldX: { $in: optRegexp } } );
```

This works for [$all](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) either.

I hope this helps!

p.s.: This was my solution to search by tags in a web application.

Comment: worked for Ruby needs as well thanks.. just used `Regexp.new(opt, Regexp::IGNORECASE)` in place of `new RegExp(tag, "i") `

Comment: What will be the java code to run this Example in Java or Spring mongodbTemplete.

Comment: Can be simplified to `var optRegexp = optValues.map(value => new RegExp("^" + value + "$", "i");` to use with `{ $in: optRegexp }`

Answer (score 4):

This works for me perfectly.

From code we can create custom query like this:

```py
{
  "first_name":{
    "$in":[
      {"$regex":"^serina$","$options":"i"}, 
      {"$regex":"^andreW$","$options":"i"}
    ]
  }
}
```

This will transform to following in mongo after query:

```
db.mycollection.find({"first_name":{"$in":[/^serina$/i, /^andreW$/i]}})
```

Same for "$nin".

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple

```
const sampleData = [
  RegExp("^" + 'girl' + "$", 'i'),
  RegExp("^" + 'boy' + "$", 'i')
];
const filerObj = { gender : {$in : sampleData}};
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it in Java is:

```
List<String> nameList = Arrays.asList(name.split(PATTERN));
List<Pattern> regexList = new ArrayList<>();
for(String name: nameList) {
regexList.add(Pattern.compile(name , Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
}
criteria.where("Reference_Path").in(regexList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my **case insensitive** search (query) with multiple condition (regex) from data of array, I've used `$in` but it doesn't support case insensitive search.

Example Data

```
{ 
  name : "...Event A",
  tags : ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4] 
},
{ 
  name : "...Event B",
  tags : ["tag3", "tag2"]
},
{ 
  name : "...Event C",
  tags : ["tag1", "tag4"]
},
{ 
  name : "...Event D",
  tags : ["tag2", "tag4"]
}
```

My query

```
db.event.find(
  { $or: //use $and or $or depends on your needs
    [ 
      { tags : { 
         $elemMatch : { $regex : '^tag1$', $options : 'i' }
        } 
      },
      { tags : { 
         $elemMatch : { $regex : '^tag3$', $options : 'i' }
        } 
      }
    ]
})
```