# Case Insensitive search with $in Mongodb - Java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Is their any way to search a column in a collection in mongodb with $in which includes an array of elements for search and also caseInsensitive matching of those elements in the column ?
N.B: I can use either Java-Mongodb or SpringMongodb Templete

Comment: Repeat for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700921/case-insensitive-search-with-in/33418202 but this is required for Java

Comment: hi @LhoBen Ben I already mentioned , I need the same for Java Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with Spring Data Mongodb if you need one item of "yourArray" to match acase insensitive string:

```
query = new Query(Criteria.where("yourArray").regex(Pattern.compile("SEARCH", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)));
```

If you need `"yourArray` elements to be in an array of case insensitive `SEARCH` items, you would use `$in` in MongoDB. Then, consider building a regex query string appending "`|`" to each item, or build an `AggregaationOperation` composed of one `MatchOperation` for each item.