# How to query elements inside an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How do i query any objects whos array contains a player with a matching case-insensitive name? `db.collection.find(players.name: search)`

This is a example object of how the data is stored (I've removed all irrelevant fields to the question).

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d67f29ae6504b451c3aca3e"), "players" : [
 { "name" : "Jenny"}, { "name" : "Benny"}, { "name" : "Kenny" } ] }
```

One solution would be to just iterate through all documents in the collection and then in turn iterate through all names in each document but I'm trying to avoid this. Another is perhaps to map names to objectIds?

Comment: I've done case insenstive before, I'm having problem with the inside an array bit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700921/case-insensitive-search-with-in

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to do this:

`db.collection.find("players.name": {'$regex' : '^string$', '$options' : 'i'})`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks $elemMatch was indeed the solution.

```
dbo.collection('replays').find({ players: {
        $elemMatch: {name : {$regex: new RegExp('^'+ search + '$', "i") }} 
    }
}).toArray(function (err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my, apparently more traditional, take on it. I didn't know a construct like your own answer here uses exists in the language, I have to do some reading. Anyway, here we go.

```
function find_player( data, player_name )
{
    return data.filter( (o) => {
        return o.players.find( (player) => {
            return player.name == player_name;
        });
    });
}

let objects = [
    { "_id" : "foo", "players" : [ { "name" : "Jenny"}, { "name" : "Benny"}, { "name" : "Kenny" } ] },
    { "_id" : "bar", "players" : [ { "name" : "Johnny"}, { "name" : "Bunny"}, { "name" : "Kinny" } ] }
];

let found = find_player(objects, "Kinny");

console.log( found[0]._id ); // bar
```