# Mongo Query with Regex in Node JS operating ON A VARIABLE

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a problem here. I want to query my MongoDB in my Node JS file using something like LIKE for a conventional relational db. The problem is the thing I want to LIKE to is not a literal...it is a variable! I have found no good way to do this as of yet. Here was the "durrr first try" shot I took at it:

```
var result = postData.replace(/\+/g,' ').substring(5);
db.testlogwiki.find({"line_text" : /result/ };
//predictably only matches to the literal "result" as opposed to my variable
```

testlogwiki is made in Mongo...I have it running and this does mach to db entries with "line_text" containing "result" literally.

It seems like a very simple question...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.testlogwiki.find({"line_text" : new RegExp(result) };
```

Comment: You're a saint. Will accept this when I get home (I have a time in which I cannot accept).

Comment: Hope your variable doesn't have any regex special characters in it or this will fail!

Answer (score 5):

Both will work

```
db.testlogwiki.find({"line_text" : new RegExp(result, 'i') }; // to make this case insensitive
```

or

```
db.testlogwiki.find( { line_text: { $regex: result[, $options: 'i'] } } );
```

Answer (score 4):

**All of the other answers may fail depending on your input variable**

You can use RegExp as others have indicated but you must escape special regex characters or else this can fail.

Lodash has a function to do this (if you aren't using it you probably should be, it adds a lot of sugar that isn't even in the ES6+ spec)

https://lodash.com/docs#escapeRegExp

`db.COLLECTION.find({FIELD_NAME: new RegExp(_.escapeRegExp(VAR), 'i') };`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the $regex option.

```
db.testlogwiki.find( { line_text: { $regex: result[, $options: 'i'] } } );
```