# how to pass a variable to a regex

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb

I have a find statement like this

```
collSession.find({"Venue.type": /.*MT.*/}).toArray(function (err, _clsSession)
        {
            console.log(_clsSession);
        });
```

It is giving answer.But i need to some value of variable instead of that harcoded value MT.
How to achieve this ?
Thanks.

**UPDATE** I tried like "/.*"+searchterm+".*/"
Its not working.

Comment: Just an FYI if you hadn't already realized this about MongoDB and regular expressions -- your search will hit every document in the searched collection, every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the inline syntax to create a regular expression, you can also use the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object to create one based on a string

```
var searchPhrase = "MT";
var regularExpression = new RegExp(".*" + searchPhrase + ".*");
collSession.find({"Venue.type": regularExpression}) [...]
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `/.*MT.*/` with `new RegExp( ".*" + variable + ".*" )`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  var pattern = 'concatenate string' + here,
        regexp = new Regexp(pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728043/mongo-query-with-regex-in-node-js-operating-on-a-variable)

it is "Venue.type": new RegExp(queryParams.et)

Answer (score 0):

> Take a look at this code: (I'm using mongoose)

```
exports.getSearchPosts = (req, res, next) => {
const keyword = req.body.keyword;
Post.find({ postTitle: new RegExp( ".*" + keyword + ".*" ) }).then(posts => {
    res.render('post/search', {
        pageTitle: 'Search result for: ' + keyword,
        posts: posts,
        category: postCategory,
        posts: catPost,
    });
 }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

**I think you will find it helpful**