# search records that have special characters in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb

I have this kinds of record in mongoDB.which has brackets and other characters.API is also passing same name in parameters. But due to brackets can't search records and can't pass params without brackets. Is there anyway to search exact same records with special characters ?

```
   {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a67295523aba20014e2fed6"
    },

    "customerName": "X-TERRA EXCAVATING AND GRADING (XTEL6K-27-B-No Tier 2)",  
}
```

Now my search query in node.js to find customer name is

```
models.customer.find({ "customerName": { $regex: '.*' + customerName + '.*', $options: 'i' } },
   function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
 }
```

But it does not return any record. If I pass customer name without records it return records. What regex should be used to search any kind of names with this special characters ?

Comment: That is because your `customerName` contains `(` and `)` that must be escaped in regex. Also, `.*` are redundant.

Comment: Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44570128/3832970) answer might be of help, too.

Comment: I am passing same customer name as param as it is in db. If I remove ( and ) it won't search anything. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Do not remove the parentheses, escape them.