# mongoDb ignore Capital

Tags: string, mongodb, request

I'd like to set a mongoDb request ignoring capitals

If I only have one user with test username

```
db.users.find(
    { username: "test" }
)
```

will return something
I'd like to return the profile test with

```
db.users.find(
    { username: "Test" }
)
```

or

```
db.users.find(
    { username: "tEsT" }
)
```

But I don"t know I to ignore capitals

same problem if I have a username Toby I'd like to find with

```
db.users.find(
    { username: "toby" }
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate, rich answers could be found there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to ignore capitals like:

```
db.users.find({username: /test/i})
```

Whereby the `i` option state case insensitive. This however is not very index friendly.

A better option is to do this client side. Normalise your case so that everything is either lower case or upper case. That way you can just test as normal.