# Search by string in Mongodb

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, rack

I need to find the items from MongoDb db using Mongoid gem in rack application. Here is what I have:

```
items = items.any_of(
                            {item_id: q},   #ok
                            {title: /q/},
                            {title2: /q/},
                            {code: q},      #ok
                            {seller: q}     #ok
                          )
```

I need to improve search by `title` and `title2`.

First off, how to make it **not** case sensitive? 
Secondly, if `q` contains many words, I want it to search by any word it contains.

How can I do that?

Comment: Suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like for the /.q./ syntax. And, add an /i  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query

Comment: Thank you. What about "if q contains many words..."?

Comment: Do you mean, "This is my title" and you want to search for "my"? The first link should work for that. If not, you could search by breaking phrases into arrays and doing "$in", but you'll not get the "contains" style string matching and it would be case sensitive. You could write JavaScript to do the search in a $where, but it's not going to be fast as it brute-forces the entire collection of documents and executes JavaScript for each. Full text search "coming" to mongoDB: http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/roadmap-15607515, or maybe: https://github.com/aaw/mongoid_fulltext