# In Android, how do I make a case-insensitive query on Kinvey datastore?

Tags: android, datastore, case-insensitive, kinvey

I am using [Kinvey](http://www.kinvey.com/) as my back-end for my android app. I have followed the guide on their datastore querying found [here](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/datastore#querying). It seems that the queries are **case-sensitive**.

How do I make a **case-insensitive** query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted the same question in the Kinvey forums, and I got the following answer:

> The Query class has a regex(String field, String regex) method which you can use for this by defining a case-insensitive regex.
>
> Something like:
>   Query myQuery = new Query().regex("myJSONKey", myRegex);
>
> Here is the documentation: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/reference/api/java/reference/com/kinvey/java/Query.html#regEx(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)

Credit to Edward Fleming.

However, for anyone who is interested, according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4441412/1434283):

> It should be noted that searching with regex's case insensitive /i means that mongodb cannot search by index, so queries against large datasets can take a long time.

I believe Kinvey uses mongodb for their datastore. Anyways, I used the suggestion mention in the same post, and it works perfectly.