# How php mongodb sort case insensitive

Tags: php, mongodb

i am facing problem with php mongodb sort case insensitive,how i can sort sot with case insensitive?
below is my code

```
$competency = $this->collection->find()->sort(array( "name" => 1 ));
```

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query

Comment: Mention data on which you want to perform sort.

Comment: @Mayuri its not duplicate,i am willing to sort ascending with case insensitive

Comment: See the comments properly. I am not commented as duplicate.

Comment: @Mayuri,Ohh, not duplicate,basically i am willing to sort ascending with case insensitive.eg R,r etc

Comment: It would be quite a terrible idea to use regex or the aggregation framework for this, instead you will want to add a normalised version of your data and index that, any other method will either kill any performance you get (a.k.a why are you using MongoDB over SQL?) or will not scale at all

Answer (score 2):

Not something you can do with find but you can rig this up with aggregate. So considering the documents:

```js
{ "a" : "zzz" }
{ "a" : "AAA" }
{ "a" : "BBB" }
{ "a" : "ccc" }
{ "a" : "ZZZ" }
```

You would issue an aggregate statement like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Use the $match statement just the same as a find
    //{ "$match": { */Some Statement /*  } }

    // Project a lowercased field
    { "$project": { 
        "a": 1,
        "sortKey": { "$toLower": "$a" }
    }},

    // Sort on that field
    { "$sort": { "sortKey": 1 } },

    // Optionally remove that field
    { "$project": {
        "a": 1
    }}      
 ])
```

So that gives you:

```js
{ "a" : "AAA" }
{ "a" : "BBB" }
{ "a" : "ccc" }
{ "a" : "zzz" }
{ "a" : "ZZZ" }
```

As opposed to the normal `.find()` form:

```js
db.collection.find().sort({ "a": 1 })

{ "a" : "AAA" }
{ "a" : "BBB" }
{ "a" : "ZZZ" }
{ "a" : "ccc" }
{ "a" : "zzz" }
```

Comment: Can you make its query?

Comment: as i am sorting on name field

Comment: @MuhammadRashid We show you how to do it, but we do not write your code for you. There is more than enough here for you do complete your work.

Comment: @MuhammadRashid Note how the example actually uses two different fields. I think I already stated that we do not write your code for you.

Answer (score 2):

Although MondoDB does not offer it, but you can very easily do it in PHP. Here is how to do it.

```
$cn = new MongoClient($dbHost);
$db = $cn->selectDB($dbName);
$col = new MongoCollection($db, $collectionName);

$cursor = $col->find();
$cursor = iterator_to_array($cursor);

foreach ($cursor as $key => $row) {
    $name[$key] = $row['name'];
    $email[$key] = $row['email'];
}
//$name is the field to sort on, taken from the above loop
//You can use SORT_ASC or SORT_DESC

array_multisort($name, SORT_ASC, $cursor);

foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    echo $doc['name'].'-'.$doc['email'].'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: This answer is out of date. MongoDB now has case insensitive index handling along with collations.

I am going to put this as an answer since it is the best option right now from what I can see.

You can use aggregation framework, as shown by @Neil. This approach is not a good one in my opinion.

First it will iterate throughout the whole result set, projecting a computed field (stored in memory) which will then do an in memory sort (limited to about 32MB of RAM, or in some cases 10% of system RAM, this may have changedin version 2.6 with using the `$out` option, either way it is still extremely inefficient, not to mention IO bottleneck of `$out`) of all these documents one by one.

Instead I would store two forms of your field, one raw and one normalised and sort on normalised, or just ignore a raw version and store strictly normalised.