# perform a search in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a list of generated users, which I filter like this:

```
roleShow: function() {
  var role = this.params.role
  return this.render('contactsList', {
    data: Meteor.users.find({ roles: role });
  });
}
```

When I create the users, I index their `profile.name` so that I can perform a search on it.

```
var id = Accounts.createUser({
  email: userData.email,
  profile: {
    name: userData.name + ' ' + userData.surname
  }
});
Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, userData.roles);
Meteor.users._ensureIndex({ "profile.name": "text" });
```

Now I am trying to filter on the client in a template.

```
Template.patientList.events({
  'input #search': function(e) {
    var results = Meteor.users.runCommand("text", {
      search: e.target.value
    });
  }
});
```

However, I can't perform `runCommand` on the `Meteor.users` collection. How could I perform this search?

(Note: I have enabled full text search already)

Comment: `Meteor.users.find({'profile.name':{$regex: 'example'}})`

Comment: isn't this case sensitive though?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query