# How to create a function for dynamic find document in Metor.js?

Tags: meteor

I want to create a function for dynamic find document in Meteor.js.
For instance I have `Students` Collection and I want to find students by `name, gender, phone...`. if name is provide I want to find name `like` the name that is provided, if `gender` is provide I want to find gender which is equal to gender that is provided, if `phone` is provide I want to find phone like the phone that is provided, and if `name` or `gender` or `phone` is not provided, I want to find the all the name and all gender and all phone. 
 In SQL Server I will create the stored Procedure like this:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[pG_Student]    
   @pName nvarchar(250)=null,
   @pGender nvarchar(50)=null,
   @pPhone nvarchar(100)=null
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StudentView]
    WHERE (LOWER(Name) like '%'+LOWER(@pName)+'%'  or @pName is null)
    and (Gender=@pGender or @pGender is null) 
    and (LOWER([Phone]) like '%'+LOWER(@pPhone)+'%'  or @pPhone is null) 
END
```

With this Stored Procedure I can call with C#.

How about with Meteor.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just need to construct your criteria. e.g.:

```
var criteria = {};
if (typeof pName != 'undefined') criteria.pName = pName.toLowerCase();
if (typeof pGender != 'undefined') criteria.pGender = pGender;
if (typeof pPhone != 'undefined') criteria.pPhone = pPhone.toLowerCase();

var cursor = Students.find(criteria);
```

Note that in the code above I'm assuming that the data in the database is already in lower case. This allows for the most efficient search. If not, you have to use a regular expression:

[MongoDB: Is it possible to make a case-insensitive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query)

That, however, isn't not advisable since Mongo can't us an index. If necessary, you could create a lowercase searchable field and a mixed case display field.

Tim