# Exact search in mongodb 2.6, just only case insensitive

Tags: regex, mongodb

Using regex = `{ name : { $regex : inputName, $options: 'i' } }`

even when input name is blank, the query returns the first document.
Even when input is `a`, query returns the first document which have `a` anywhere in the name.

I want if then input name is "jo", then it should only return the first document either with name "Jo", "JO", "jO", "jo".

Please remember i recieve inputName as variable

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this does not work.

Comment: Yeah, I updated my answer after double checking.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry for my previous comment i checked with some syntax error. Now your answer works good.

Comment: The question is not about how to make a search case insensitive, but how to perform an exact search. Thus, [*MongoDB: Is it possible to make a case-insensitive query?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query) is not the *exact duplicate* of this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a JS `RegExp` constructor to build a regexp dynamically:

```
new RegExp("^" + inputName + "$", "i")
```

The `i` modifier will provide case insensitive matching and `^` / `$` anchors will make sure the full string match will be requried.

Comment: Don't think `$regex` in Mongo can use `A` flag: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: @NickBull: You think or you tried and it did not work? Not sure you have noticed - I also reference that link in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I have double-checked and it seems that there is no full-fledged PCRE support in MongoDB regex queries, that is a great pity 3rd party apps "truncate" great PCRE features.

Comment: Agreed! -1 removed