# MongoDB: Find all lower/uppercase duplicates in DB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

There is a huge collection with 600.000 documents. Unfortunatly there are duplicates, which I want to find.
These duplicates differs only in first letter upper/lower case.

```
{ key: 'Find me' },
{ key: 'find me' },
{ key: 'Don't find me }, // just one document for this string
{ key: 'don't find me either } // just one document for this string
```

Now I want to get all duplicates, which means there is an existing uppercase AND lowercase string.

Comment: 600k doesn't seem like a lot. Assuming these strings are not too long (i.e. not books) all of them should fit in memory. With an average of 80 chars (~one line in terminal) per document it is only ~48Mb. Thus I suggest just loading all of them to a database client and do processing in memory. It could be done with Mongo as well (db-side functions) but it will block whole database. Also you could try map/reduce but it seems to be more complex solution. I think that's all choices you've got.

Comment: Sounds good, as every entry is really small (avrg 10-20 characters), then it would be a normal javascript question to get duplicates out of an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MongoDB, there is a `$toLower` transformation available that you can use.

Here is a way to output every key appearing more than once (you need to change `db.collection` by the name of your collection):

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { $group: 
        { 
            _id: { $toLower: "$key" }, 
            cnt: { "$sum": 1 } 
        }
    },
    { $match: 
        { cnt: {$gt: 1 } } 
    }
])
```

First, the `$group` groups the documents by `key` (case insensitive). The number of documents for each key is accumulated in `cnt`. For after the `$group`, you end up with something like:

```
 {"key": "find me", "cnt": 2}
 {"key": "other key", "cnt": 1}
 ...
```

Then, the `$match` filters those results, retaining only the ones with a `cnt` greated than 1.

**Note**: above is the code for the mongo shell. You can do pretty much the same from javascript (using the mongodb driver), but you need to add quotes around `$group` and such.

Comment: I copied-paste and changed the wrong fields... Fixed it. Sorry.

Comment: For the record, as it's not clear enough imo, the key name **must** be prefixed by `$`

Answer (score 0):

Here is find query it will find user collection where name => harendra or name => Harendra both case match (small and capital letters).

```
User.findOne({name: {$regex: '^Harendra$', $options: 'i'}})
```