# How to query MongoDB only Case insensitive from Go

Tags: mongodb, go

I tried to query:

```
bson.M{"name": bson.M{"$regex": bson.RegEx{Pattern: "sophia", Options: "i"}}
```

but, it also query out which part matched with "sophia".

I only want to query out the items which case insensitive.

Comment: e.g the items with name "so" also be queried from above code

Comment: I don't understand your question. You seem to be saying that the query does what you want... ?

Comment: In addition to using a correct regular expression to match your "word only", if you go way down the list of answers on the MongoDB specific question you will [see one that covers case insensitive collation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40914924/2313887) as is now supported in modern releases of MongoDB. This would generally be preferable for an "exact match" than using a regex.