# AND operator in mongodb regex

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, regex-lookarounds

In a mongo database with an array field titled interests, 
when i need to look for people interested in either judo OR mma, i write the query like this:

`{interests : {$regex: "judo|mma", $options: 'i'}}`

How do i find people interested in judo AND mma?

Note: 
I've tried the following and various variations of these but none seem to work :

```
{interests : {$regex: "(?=judo)(?=mma)", $options: 'i'}},
{interests : {$regex: "(?=.*judo)(?=.*mma)", $options: 'i'}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Currently, you're trying to check if a string is both at the same time "judo" and "mma". This of course is never happening. Can you provide an example on how your data is structured in this case ?

Comment: `(?=.*judo)(?=.*mma)` should work.

Comment: @Pac0 sure! inrerests is an array of this structure:
``` interests : { type: Array, default: [] } ```

Comment: can you try something like : 

`{interests: {$all: [/^judo/, /^mma/], , $options: 'i'}}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's an array , that contain maybe elements like either "judo", "mma", or "other", or none of them. It's not one comma separated string where you perform one search. like in "judo, other, mma"

Comment: @Pac0 thank you so much it works! but to use options, i need to use regex otherwise it's giving me an error. any workaround to do a case insenstive search?

Comment: can you try adding the 'i' just after each regex like this instead :$all: [/^judo/i, /^mma/i

Comment: (like here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should work :

```
{interests: {$all: [/^judo$/i, /^mma$/i]}
```

Comment: is there anyway to do this case insensitive search if the array is being sent directly to the function? eg. array: `["judo","mma"]`

Comment: You can dynamically map each string of the array to a regexp by using `map` and `new RegExp` : `["judo","mma"].map(x => new RegExp(x, "i"))` (I'll let you add the anchors `^` and `$` around the string `x` if you want). The output will be an array of regexps, so it should work (not tested, no mongodb near me)