# Bson Filters MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

I'm looking for a method that is like equalsIgnoreCase, only in Bson Filters.

At the moment I use `Filters.eq (" tag ", tag)` only I want a method where the tag can also be case sensitive, but still comes true. So, so to speak, equalsIgnoreCase if you understand what I mean.

`return collection.find(Filters.eq("tag", tag)).first() != null;`

Comment: Take a look at [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html#regex), [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/index.html#collation), and [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html#text)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use regex for that. Here is a similar issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1863452/2241072