# How can I have a case insensitive unique index in AWS DocumentDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

In MongoDB (which this is supposed to emulate) you would do something like this:

```
 { unique: true, name: 'name', collation: { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } }
```

But in AWS DocumentDB I get `Field 'collation' is currently not supported`

I'm hoping there is a way to do this without doing something silly like adding an extra property which is the lower cased version of the field.

Comment: Sean, Amazon DocumentDB does not support collation. For your case, one way to workaround this is to add an extra field, create index on it and then copy data from original field to the new field.

Comment: It's possible to run [MongoDB Atlas on AWS](https://www.mongodb.com/mongodb-on-aws). By running actual MongoDB you don't have to deal with DocumentDB limitations. Atlas has a forever free tier and more granular control.
If migrating is a viable option, this [migration guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/guides/cloud/migrate-from-aws-to-atlas-on-aws/) may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote to AWS Support. The only suggestion which they have provided **is to use regex search query**.

Regex search requires to scan collection instead of using an index, **which practically is not a feasible solution at all.**

Example of regex search query (use only in case you have a small database):

```
Inserted only one document as below:
=================================
query: db.stuff.save({"foo":"bar"});
result: WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })


Performed the case insensitive search using regex:
==========================================
query: db.stuff.find( { foo: /^bar$/i } );
result: { "_id" : ObjectId("5f6848669a547e3b679499e2"), "foo" : "bar" }

query: db.stuff.find( { foo: /^BAR$/i } );
result:{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f6848669a547e3b679499e2"), "foo" : "bar" }


Inserted stemmed dcouments of the previous filed value:
================================================
query: db.stuff.save({"foo":"barxyz"});
result: WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })


The search query with regex still works well:
========================================
query: db.stuff.find( { foo: /^BAR$/i } );
result: { "_id" : ObjectId("5f6848669a547e3b679499e2"), "foo" : "bar" }

query: db.stuff.find( { foo: /^bar$/i } );
result: { "_id" : ObjectId("5f6848669a547e3b679499e2"), "foo" : "bar" }
```

**They couldn't tell me when collation or case insensitive index feature will be supported:**

> I cannot provide ETA in this regard as support of any new feature requires regressive testing by the development and has to go through various stages of software development lifecycle.

Linking MongoDB answer: [MongoDB: Is it possible to make a case-insensitive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query)

Comment: Disappointing AWS DocumentDB support. I just ran on the collation not supported issue, and all my implementation that used collation insensitive for case insensitive searches has been affected when moving from MongoDb to DocumentDB.

An expression filter like `x.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Equals("foo".ToLowerInvariant());` is not supported either with C# driver.

Answer (score 1):

DocumentDB is not mongodb and even if it works for most things you'll realize that you'll run into this type of problems the more granular you get with your queries.

Go here for the support APIs [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html)

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon DocumentDB now supports the ability for `$regex` operators to utilize an index. To utilize an index with the `$regex` operator, you must use the `hint()` command and specify the name of the field you are applying the `$regex` on.

For example, if you have an index named `product_1` on field `product`, you can perform a `$regex` search on the following documents as follows:

`db.foo.insert({"product": "a product"})`

`db.foo.insert({"product": "another product"})`

`db.foo.createIndex({"product":1})`

Use hint on field `product`:

`db.foo.find({"product":{$regex:/^A pro/i}}).hint({"product":1})`

`db.foo.find({"product":{$regex:/^ANOT/i}}).hint({"product":1})`

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.regex-indexing for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation mentions: _The use of an index for a $regex query is optimized for regex queries that utilize a prefix and do not specify the `I`, `m`, or `o` regex options._

There is no `I` flag, so this surely means the `i` flag. This also matches my tests, which show a speedup when running this against a large collection only for patterns that don't specify `i`.