# find document node using string based lower case or upper case

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb

I have mongo db data like this,

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "62bd29431e2e2feca0c53cd2" },
  "inspectionType": "hai2",
  "interval": 1,
  "companyId": { "$oid": "62b4aee8e86962a28632a01a" },
  "createdAt": { "$date": "2022-06-30T04:40:35.946Z" },
  "updatedAt": { "$date": "2022-06-30T04:40:35.946Z" },
  "__v": 0
}
```

User Input String is : inspection =  **'Hai2'** Or **'hai2'**

I have to find the that document using above the string . I have used below the query but getting empty response.

```
return db.inspectionCollection
    .find({ inspectionType: inspection, companyId })
    .sort({ updatedAt: -1 })
    .lean(true)
    .catch((err: Error) => {
      logger.error(err);
      return [];
    });
```

So, What exact query format to getting the documents using string ?

Comment: What is the current output you are getting ? and empty array or a different ID ?

Comment: Getting empty array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: Is it possible to make a case-insensitive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query)

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest using `$regex` with options "im" which matches with case-insensitive (`i`) and full string (from start to end) (`m`).

```
db.collection.find({
  inspectionType: {
    $regex: "hai2",
    $options: "mi"
  },
  companyId: {
    "$oid": "62b4aee8e86962a28632a01a"
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2IYIacGXEvl)

```
return db.inspectionCollection
    .find({ 
        inspectionType: {
            $regex: inspection, 
            $options: "im"
        },
        companyId: /* Value with ObjectId type */
    })
    .sort({ updatedAt: -1 })
    .lean(true)
    .catch((err: Error) => {
      logger.error(err);
      return [];
    });
```

Comment: I have used this query , now it's working .
Thanxs @Yong Shun