# How to make search query in mongoose to find only that "key" having value "singleWord" (omit string having more that 1 words in string)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a moongoose app and facing issue to search the data having single val in string

e.g.

```
Data :[
        { "name": "Shubham"},
        {"name":"Shubham Sharma"},
        {"name":"Sharma"}
      ]
```

Search result for "Shubham" should be

```
[
    { "name": "Shubham"}
]
```

Using this query I am not able to achieve my goal

```
var regexp = new RegExp(`^${name.toLowerCase()}`);
 let promise = await usersModel.find({ name: regexp }).limit(40)
.collation({ locale: "en", caseLevel: true })
    .exec(async function (err, users) {
        if (err) {
          return users;
        }})
      throw err;
    });
```

Comment: your regex matches every string that starts with `name.toLowerCase()` you probably want to add a `$` to the end to indicate that the string has to finish after that. Is there a specific reason why you use a regex? why can't you simply go with `{name: name.toLowerCase()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [`$regex`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) within your query, and enabling the `i` option for case insensitive matching, you shouldn't need to transform your input string at all.

Example playground - https://mongoplayground.net/p/tHap2kGneOa

Query:

```
db.collection.find({
  name: {
    $regex: "^Shubham$", // ^ = Starts with. $ = Ends with
    $options: "i" // i = case insensitive
  }
})
```

Which will match:

```
Shubham
shubham
```

but not:

```
Sharma Shubham
Sharma
Shubham Sharma
```

Update - Based on comments.

Note: In this instance of case insensitive absolute string matching, you could also take advantage of collations - [MongoDB: Is it possible to make a case-insensitive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863399/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-make-a-case-insensitive-query/#answer-40914924)

Comment: Btw thank you so much for telling me about $options. it will really going to help me. I am new to mongoose, i know only basics.

Comment: I want to omit last result from here only need shubham/Shubham in results

Comment: So, you want it to be case insensitive, but ONLY match the whole of the string? if `Shubham` should match ONLY `Shubham` and `shubham`. Is that right? If that is the case, just add a `$` at the end of the string, eg `^Shubham$` - Example - https://mongoplayground.net/p/tHap2kGneOa

Comment: Thank you its working fine now ! i am marking this as an answer, also edited as you mentioned in comment to add  `$`